# Disable shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Working with the PayPal API and using the Name-Value Pair Interface PHP source codes from [SDKs and Downloads: Simplify Integrations with Downloads and SDKs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks).

My question is similar to "[Removing (or prefilling) the address details for PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215704/removing-or-prefilling-the-address-details-for-paypal-express-checkout)" but I don't want shipping cost/address or anything related about shipping at all.

I keep all shipping details on my system (even sometimes shipping doesn't even apply and there is no charge for it) and I just want user to pay through PayPal without shipping address and shipping cost.

How can I disable shipping part of checkout?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're using the newer API, you could also pass NOSHIPPING=1 (not no_shipping)

Further details about all possible parameters to the SetExpressCheckout here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/nvp/

Or lookup for [Payment experience](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/) in new REST API

Comment: I've added here full request examples to start a transaction, commit and read payment details, with item details be displayed on paypal site and merchant transaction history. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16638936/185565

Comment: It appears that this works also with the old api, at least it behaves so in the sandbox.

Answer (score 21):

For others looking for this, because PayPals documentation is so GREAT (cough, cough).

NO web experience profile REQUIRED!

Using REST API V2 with Javascript/JQuery and turning "Ship To" off for an ORDER, here is the correct code example:

```
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        $('#paypalmsg').html('<b>' + 'WAITING ON AUTHORIZATION TO RETURN...' + '</b>');
        $('#chkoutmsg').hide()
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                description: 'GnG Order',
                amount: {
                    value: cartTotal
                }
            }],
            application_context: {
              shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
            }

        });
    },
```

Comment: Thank you oh soo much for this! saved my day! any chance you could point me to where you got this?

Comment: I wrote it, gleaming it from their horrible docs

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I was stuck on this for a good while. It is almost impossible not to land on docs labelled 'Legacy' , which do not work. I certainly did not spot `application_context`. Saved my day.

Comment: Used to create an order for client-side integrations. Accepts the same options as the request body of the [/v2/checkout/orders api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body).

Answer (score 15):

Hey Ergec, just pass along the `no_shipping` parameter with a value of `1`.

From PayPal's [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables):

```
no_shipping

Do not prompt payers for shipping address. Allowable values:
0 – prompt for an address, but do not require one
1 – do not prompt for an address
2 – prompt for an address, and require one
The default is 0.
```

Comment: I put no_shipping=1 into $nvpstr but still it asks for shipping. And I just noticed that it's adding tax too. All prices include tax already so I need to get rid of tax field too. Please help!!

Comment: ok here is what I did and worked. It's not adding shipping cost and tax anymore. Just commented out current $nvpstr variable in ReviewOrder and put this line

$nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $amount . "&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL ."&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

$amount is sent from modified SetExpressCheckout.php . Removed all input boxes and left paymentType, currencyCodeType and amount only.

Comment: Yes. 7 years later, tried the new NOSHIPPING =1 didn't work. Tried no_shipping = 1, it worked. August 2017.

Comment: Sept 2017, something changed this month at paypal, some of my payments started failing saying invalid address, but the address was fine, so I tried &address_override=1&no_shipping=1, it worked! yes i am using the older API at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?

Comment: Provided link is absolete

Answer (score 8):

The current right answer is **depracated**. To fix the issue in new API we should create **Payment web experience profile resource** with needed parameters and attach it to request **Payment** .

**Example in PHP:**

```
/** Note: Define some variables yourself. */

$inputFields = new InputFields();
$inputFields->setAllowNote(true)
    ->setNoShipping(1) // Important step
    ->setAddressOverride(0);

$webProfile = new WebProfile();
$webProfile->setName(uniqid())
    ->setInputFields($inputFields)
    ->setTemporary(true);

$createProfile = $webProfile->create($apiContext);

$payment = new Payment();

$payment->setPayer($payer);
$payment->setIntent($intent);
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->setExperienceProfileId($createProfile->getId()); // Important step.

$payment->create($apiContext);

if ($payment->getState() === "created") {
    $approvalLink = $payment->getApprovalLink()

    header("Location: $approvalLink"); // Redirects user to PayPal page.
}
```

**Note:** You can find all above used classes by link: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/lib/PayPal/Api

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly fine. FYI, you can also create a web profile once and use the same id for future payments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734909/paypal-payment-rest-api-web-experience-profile/32758454

Answer (score 6):

To solve for this from current (2019) web client .JS, add the `application_context` block to the request body.

Below is an example for `createSubscription()` call; and I'm thinking this will work with `createOrder()` as well

```
paypal.Buttons({
          createSubscription: function (data, actions) {

              return actions.subscription.create({

                  'plan_id'            : 'P-123',
                  'application_context': {
                      'shipping_preference': 'NO_SHIPPING'
                  }
              });
          },

          onApprove: function (data, actions) {

              // ...
          }
      })
      .render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Thanks to the example code here:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/#4-create-a-subscription

Here's where the field enums are listed:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout-API-Operation-NVP/

Comment: for createOrder() it is not showing the address fields but the transaction is getting failed

Comment: I did not actually try this with `createOrder()`, so do not have any insight on an implementation with that call; or if it is in fact possible with the solution I describe here. I would share your issue via a new post, where you can provide the code snippet(s) you are attempting to implement along with any relevant notes.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am attempting to write a code for paypal smart button implementation with address disabled.
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client
here is the extact code where I am trying to disable the address on click of credit card

Comment: same solution is give here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631779/paypal-js-sdk-smart-payment-disable-address-promt-for-creditcard-payment-witho

but again the issue is payment is rejected without address.

Answer (score 2):

Create a web profile based on the example found in the API: `CreateWebProfile.php`.

```
$createProfileResponse = require  __DIR__ . '/CreateWebProfile.php';
$payment = new Payment(); 
$payment->setExperienceProfileId($createProfileResponse->getId());
```

File path: `paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/payment-experience/CreateWebProfile.php`

Answer (score 2):

### 2022 and beyond

The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context) for V2 of the PayPal API, currently the latest version, and which seems to have been cleaned up a lot over the past year or so, states the following:

> shipping_preference
>
> Displays the shipping address to the customer.
> Enables the customer to choose an address on the PayPal site.
> Restricts the customer from changing the address during the payment-approval process.
>
> The possible values are:
>
> GET_FROM_FILE. Use the customer-provided shipping address on the PayPal site.
> **NO_SHIPPING. Redact the shipping address from the PayPal site. Recommended for digital goods.**
> SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS. Use the merchant-provided address. The customer cannot change this address on the PayPal site.

Therefore, simply adding:

```
"application_context" => [
    "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING"
]
```

or if using JavaScript:

```
"application_context": {
    "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING"
}
```

...to your order creation should disable any shipping options.

**As an example**, my PHP code to create an order using PayPal's Standard Checkout Integration (which in turn makes use of the Smart Buttons) now looks like this:

```
$order = $paypal->createOrder([
    "intent"=> "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units"=> [
         [
            "amount"=> [
                "currency_code" => "GBP",
                "value"=> 4.99
            ],
             'description' => 'My product description',
        ],            
    ],               
    "application_context" => [
        "shipping_preference" => "NO_SHIPPING"
    ]
]);
```

Comment: And... apparently now in Feb 2023 they are changing the API yet again. Now it says "application_context" is DEPRECATED, and we should use the "experience_context" instead. However, for the record, "application_context...shipping_preference...NO_SHIPPING" still seems to work, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

@Ergec : I tried this:

```
$nvpstr = "&ADDRESSOVERRIDE=1".$shiptoAddress."&L_NAME0=".$L_NAME0."&L_NAME1=".$L_NAME1."&L_AMT0=".$L_AMT0."&L_AMT1=".$L_AMT1."&L_QTY0=".$L_QTY0."&L_QTY1=".$L_QTY1."&MAXAMT=".(string)$maxamt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt."&AMT=".$itemamt."&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL."&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType;
```

It works. Here we can also use shipping address even though we are not charging any amount.

Comment: i think it will be ok if we are not setting the paymentType argument