# paypal express checkout shipping address required?

Tags: paypal, required

Java papal express check out feature, we are providing internet services to the user we don't have any thing to ship to user.

Do we need to provide shipping details to paypal API? If I do not, it gives me error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definetly is possible to do express checkout without shipping details.

check out this post: 
[Disable shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283251/how-to-disable-shipping-in-paypal-express-checkout)