# Disable the address fields in Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal, payment, express-checkout

I'm trying to make the Paypal Express Checkout experience the least intrusive possible to my customers, so ideally I'd like them to only provide their payment card information.

By default, Paypal asks for the full customer address + phone number as well.

I did read this question: [Disable shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283251/disable-shipping-address-option-in-paypal-express-checkout), but right now this solution just removes the address confirmation on the second page, not the address fields on the page where the card information is taken.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Do you have your customer enter their address anywhere else?

Comment: It's a food ordering system. If they order for *collection*, they don't. If they order for *delivery*, they do, but the delivery address is not necessarily the same as the billing address. I'm a bit reluctant to ask for the billing address as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not the address fields on the page where the card information is taken.

That's correct. These are used as the billing address if someone is using a guest account (no registered PayPal account), and is as such required.

Comment: can I override the billing address in that form with data from my site?