# remove shipping option using PayPal ButtonManager API

Tags: api, button, paypal

I'm using PayPal's ButtonManager API to dynamically create a hosted button. 
When the user clicks on the "buy now" button, he's taken to a payment page where he can log in to his paypal account or pay by credit card.

Now what happens is that while giving his payment info, there's also shipping address info.

What I want to do is remove shipping address option entirely. My products are digital so I'm not doing any shipping and don't want any shipping to display.

Is there any HTML variable that I can pass through the button to ensure this? I know there's a `no_shipping` variable, which allows users to enter shipping address or not, but I don't even want this. I just want *no shipping* info at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this solution for Express Checkout:

[Disable shipping address option in PayPal Express Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283251/disable-shipping-address-option-in-paypal-express-checkout)

I simply set `L_BUTTONVAR4=no_shipping=1` in the NVP query string call to the Button Manager API, and it worked!