# Paypal Payment REST API web experience profile

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I am using the paypals rest API and integrating paypal with payments.

I manage to create the web experience profile with the following code, but i cant run this code 2 times, it says the profile already exists.

does this mean that i have to create one profile and use it for all customers and all transactions ?

for how long a web experience profile is is valid for.

or do i have to change the profile name and create a new profile for each transaction ?

```
curl -v POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payment-experience/web-profiles \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>' \
  -d '{
    "name": "YeowZa! T-Shirt Shop",
    "presentation": {
    "brand_name": "YeowZa! Paypal",
    "logo_image": "site",
    "locale_code": "US"
  },
    "input_fields": {
    "allow_note": true,
    "no_shipping": 0,
    "address_override": 1
  },
    "flow_config": {
    "landing_page_type": "billing",
    "bank_txn_pending_url": "site"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There's no "lifecycle time" defined for a web experience profile, not until you update it or delete the profile
  `DELETE /v1/payment-experience/web-profiles/<Profile-Id>`
- Pass the profile ID into the JSON payload for each payment request,

  ```
  "experience_profile_id": "XP-CP6S-W9DY-96H8-MVN2"
  ```

  reuse the profile unless you need different experience settings (allow shipping / note / logo img, etc).

Check this out for more details on [Payment Experience overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/)

Comment: Link is broken. Just when I thought I had finally found what what this whole "Payment Experience" thing is about. :/

Comment: Link here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-experience/

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the previous answer -

- You *first* [Create a profile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-web-experience-profile) with a `name`
- *After it's created*, if you want to use the profile, use it's `id` (assigned to it by Paypal)

Depending on how you want to implement this, you flow could possibly be to

1. [Obtain existing profiles](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-web-experience-profiles) (if any)
2. Then evaluate whether you want to add or obtain the id

   - if `name` (or `id`) exists, obtain/use its `id`, otherwise,
   - if you *add* ([Create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-web-experience-profile)), the response will return the `id`

Hth...

Answer (score 4):

The name variable in a profile is unique per merchant.

Typically, you will create a profile once and then use that single profile multiple times.