# Paypal JS SDK Smart Payment - Disable address promt for Creditcard payment without account

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm integrating the Smart Payment Buttons in the paypal checkout

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?...>
paypal.Buttons({
createOrder(data, actions) {
// ...
onApprove(data, actions) {
// ...
}).render('#paypal-button');
```

Besides paying with a PayPal account we want to offer the User to **pay for our digital products with SEPA or Credit Card without creating a paypal account**.

What **we don't require is a billing address or shipping address input from the user.** We already have that information and handle billing ourselves, while shipping is not applicable.

**Is there any way to disable the address input** (and preferable also contact information input) using the JS SDK? Any parameter I can pass to the SDK resource or the `paypal.Buttons.render()` method? 
When paying with a Credit Card through other payment providers they never care for that user information. Just the Number, Expiration and CVS should matter for a good UX. Even entering a CC number can already be quite a pain. The same applies to payment with SEPA. I just don't want the user to have to enter their address.

Or do I have to pass the customer information to PayPal to help with fraud prevention? If so, can I at least disable the "Ship to billing address" checkbox? That might confuse our Users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You need to set **shipping_preference** parameter of the **application_context** object to **'NO_SHIPPING'**:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [{ amount: { value: 99.00 } }],

      application_context: {
        shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
      }

    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {}
}).render(button);
```

You can read more about [Application Context Object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/#definition-application_context)

Comment: Incidentally, I see that the "v1 version of the API will be deprecated soon" ([see Orders API v1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/)). That seems to be the case for the [Payments API v1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#orders), as well. What's the difference between Orders and Payments? I find the PayPal documentation a bit confusing on this topic. Here's [Application Context for Orders API v2](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-application_context).

Comment: @showdev "Order" allows you to authorize the charge and capture it later, "Payment" has to be captured right away.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, it won't work for "Credit and debit card" payments. It works only selecting "PayPal" button (and inside the popup click "Pay with a card") but not clicking  "Credit and debit card" https://snipboard.io/B8l60d.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to set shipping_type parameter 'PICKUP':

```
paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      shipping_type: 'PICKUP',
      application_context: { shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING' },
      purchase_units: [{ amount: { value: 99.00 } }]
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {}
}).render(button);
```

Comment: does the shipping_type have any effect? according to their docs, it only makes sense when providing multiple shipping options: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/shipping-options/